# PowerBI Power automate error while adding the refresh button

Tags: database, powerbi, data-analysis, power-automate

Hi I am trying to add power automate visual in my PowerBi dashboard to create a refresh button for end user but it is showing me the error, can anyone help me with this?
FYI: PowerBi Version: latest December 2023[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gUT5.png)

I want to create a refresh button for end user on the dashboard

Comment: It says it there in the error message. Seems you don't have a licence for Power Automate. Are you able to Sign in here? https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2250600&clcid=0x409&culture=en-us&country=us

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.